# How to divide Counter values by a set number?

Tags: python, counter

I have been counting the number of words that appear in a list using `collections.Counter`. My problem is however that I am now looking to divide each value by a predetermined number (in this case 14). However I am trying the below but am getting the error: `'str' object has no attribute 'values'`, which I understand, but am unsure how to correct. Here is what I currently have:

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = ['red','green','blue','red','orange','red','green']

counts = Counter(mylist)

for word in counts:
    x = word.values()/14
```

Ideally what I want to end up with is a list of dictionaries with the word as the key, and the count (divided by my preset value) as the value. Something like

```
>>> mynewlist = [{'Red', 0.214},{'Green', 0.143},{'Blue', 0.071},{'Orange', 0.071}]
```

Comment: `counts` has a `values` method. Why do you want a list of dicts as output instead of a dict?

Comment: Only because I assumed that I couldn't use values with the counts method (due to the error I'm receiving) - more than happy to stick with count if I can achieve what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to iterate on it like you would do on a normal dictionary:

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = ['red','green','blue','red','orange','red','green']

counts = Counter(mylist)
for item, count in counts.items():
    counts[item] /= 14

print(counts)
# Counter({'red': 0.21428571428571427, 'green': 0.14285714285714285, 
# 'blue': 0.07142857142857142, 'orange': 0.07142857142857142})
```

Comment: You don't use `count` in the loop, so you could simplify to `for k in counts: counts[k] /= 14`